# Joomla: Pre-Populate from using URL

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a form in an article. I will be directing people to the form from different pages and want to pre-populate some fields, depending on the page they came from.
Is there any easy way to do this in joomla 3.x?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in RSForms Pro:
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/recording-the-referer-page.html

In the same "Scripts called on form display" you could have to write the conditionals to set the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. I managed to enable javascript elements in the joomla article. I have sourced some javascript which will populate the form by id on page load.